# Canvas enabling is not working

Tags: unity, 3d

I have a canvas with two buttons in it and I want to enable it on the button click, but when I try to enable it, it doesn't work. However, when I try to disable it on button click it does work. 
Here is my code:

```
 public GameObject mycanvas;
  public  void onClick() {
     mycanvas.SetActive(true);
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the enable button is a child of the canvas, and the canvas is disabled, the button is disabled too, so you can't click it.

Moreover, are you using the `On Click ()` callback of the Button itself, by feeding it your `OnClick` method? I mean something like this:

[image]

Comment: I created a blank gameObject and assigned script to it and used in the place of "Button (1) (ButtonDisable)

Comment: yeah I disabled the canvas. Then how should I make it work?

Comment: @Hemlata Use more than one canvas (or disable only the child object(s) you want to hide, rather than everything).